# Extra slashes in Visual Studio 2008 URLs

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to debug a very old (.net 2.0) web application in Visual Studio 2008.  When I run the app the resulting url is:

http://localhost:1070///Index.aspx

Which generates a 400-bad request.  Obviously its the extra slashes the the left of Index.aspx.  I find that these appear in virtually all URLs including the ones for images.  Why is this happening?  I cannot run the app.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  Changing the WEB settings for the start path to "/" then back to "" (blank) cleared it out.  Must have been a faulty or buggy setting.